# Error: The method selectByVisibleText(string) is undefined for the type webelement

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

while adding

```
WebElement dBox1= (new WebDriverWait(driver,10))
       .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("visualizationId")))
       .selectbyVisibleText("Center");
```

in my code am getting the error The method `selectByVisibleText(string)` is undefined for the type webelement

Comment: in your code you have selectbyVisibleText the b should be capitalized I assume?

Comment: Please add your html code here.

Answer (score 1):

It is the programming issue. `elementToBeClickable` Expected condition returns the webelement object which doesn't have `selectByVisibleText(string)` method. This method belongs to `Select` class. Read [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#selectByVisibleText%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

**Please check the import package. It  should be `import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;`**